# Sharepoint 2010 - get List IRM properties with client object model

Tags: client-object-model, properties, irm

This link here shows you how to get the IRM properties of a list with the sharepoint sdk:
http://sharepoint.nauplius.net/2013/07/using-powershell-to-manage-sharepoint-information-rights-management-settings/

For example I can get the print property like this:

```
    string print = list.RootFolder.Properties["vti_irm_IrmPrint"].ToString();
```

Does anybody know how to get that property with the Client Object Model?

Thanks,

Dan